# How to JSON serialize null values but not empty values with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

There is a feature of Jackson ObjectMapper which allows empty values to be removed:

```java
class Car {
   Optional<String> ownerName;
   String manufacturer;

   public Optional<String> getOwnerName() { return ownerName; }
   public String getManufacturer() { return manufacturer; }
}

Car batMobile = new Car();
batMobile.owner = Optional.of("Batman");
batMobile.manufacturer = null;

Car stolenCar = new Car();
stolenCar.owner = Optional.empty();
stolenCar.manufacturer = "Tesla";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_ABSENT);

mapper.writeValueAsString(batMobile);
/*
{
  "ownerName": "Batman"
}
*/
mapper.writeValueAsString(stolenCar);
/*
{
  "manufacturer": "Tesla"
}
*/
```

What I want instead is for Optional.empty values to be removed, but null values to remain:

```java
mapper.writeValueAsString(batMobile);
/*
{
  "ownerName": "Batman",
  "manufacturer": null
}
*/
mapper.writeValueAsString(stolenCar);
/*
{
  "manufacturer": "Tesla"
}
*/
```

And I want this to apply globally without needing any annotations on the DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you use `java.util.Optional` be sure you have registered `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module` module which provides extra serialisers and deserialisers.

In your case the simplest way would be to use annotation on property levels:

```
class Car {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    Optional<String> ownerName;

    @JsonInclude
    String manufacturer;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Default value is `Include.ALWAYS` which should be used in your case.

If you want to do that globally you need to implement custom filter and check all cases manually. Simple example:

```
class CustomFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // return false to keep value in response
        // return true to filter out value from response
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj instanceof Optional) {
            Optional opt = (Optional) obj;
            return !opt.isPresent();
        }
        //other cases if needed

        return false;
    }
}
```

You can register it as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, CustomFilter.class, CustomFilter.class));
```

In case, this is not what you wanted you need to set globally most appropriate value and for given properties set another value. If you can not modify `DTO` classes, you can always use `MixIn` feature.

Comment: indeed but seems a requirement : `And I want this to apply globally without needing any annotations on the DTOs. `

Comment: @CodeScale, It is not an easy task to implement custom global filter. Take a look on above one to check if it will work for you.

Comment: Be aware that some things you can set-up also using application properties. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper#1-application-properties-and-custom-jackson-module or some reference here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper